# app crashes java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int:

Tags: java, android, parsing, int, android-edittext

I use this code to get a number from an EditText and pass it into a Count Down Timer

```
    final int mytime;
    mytime = Integer.parseInt(textIn.getText().toString());

    btnStartTimer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            startCountDownTimer(mytime);

        }
    });
```

However the app crashed and I get a:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int:

However when I write it like  this it works:

```
    btnStartTimer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            startCountDownTimer(Integer.parseInt(textIn.getText().toString()));

        }
    });
```

Can please someone explain me difference ? Can I use the first code somehow ?
I really don't understand the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you first example the value of the text has not been set and will be null.  You want to do the action after the use has filled in the form and clicked on the button don't you.

Comment: looks like it, unless you **want** your app to crash